# How do I access WordPress database and core files of WordPress in AWS default Bitnami installation?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami, ec2-ami

I have installed Bitnami WordPress in my AWS instance. Now I wanted to access my WordPress database and files to edit. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I could get the solution, here it is -

What is require -

- Key Pair's PEM/PPK File ( You can create new Key pairs if you don't have for old one )
- if you don't have PPK file then use PuttyGen software to create PPK from PEM file

Step starts from here -

1. Get Public IP ( EC2 > Running Instances > Click Instance > Description Public DNS (IPv4) )

   2. Open FileZilla, Enter values like

Host: Public IP/DNS
Username: (name of Operating System of your server, mine was ubuntu so username was ubuntu)
Password: leave blank 
Port: 22

3. Goto **Edit > Settings > SFTP > Add Key File.. > Select your PPK file** > **Ok**
4. Quickconnect
5. You are done.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bitnami WordPress For AWS Cloud](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/):

- If you used the AWS Marketplace, the password is available from the **Get System Log** option in the EC2 console.
- If you used Amazon Lightsail, SSH into the instance and look in the `bitnami_application_password` file